# my useState array doesn't update using spread method even when i'm doing to a copy array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, mutate

```
 export default function Calculator(props){
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('')
    const [operator,setOperator]= useState('')
    const [equationNumbers,setEquationNumbers] = useState([])
    const [result, setResult]= useState(0)

    
    /* doing the operation + - * / to the result array element  */
    function Calculate(operator){
        /* if user want to do add operation */
        if (operator === '+'){
            setResult(equationNumbers[0] + equationNumbers[1])
            setUserInput(result)
        }
    }
    /* handle operation either on keyBoard or calculator bad */
    function handleAddingOperation(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        repeatPressingOperation('if you want possitive number, use plaeas the switch button')
        setOperator('+')
        // equationNumbers.push(Number(userInput))
        let NewNum = [Number(userInput)]
        setEquationNumbers(NewNum)
        console.log(NewNum)
        setUserInput('')
    }

    function handlePressingEnterKeyOrEquallButton(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        repeatPressingOperation('you did not enter any number please try again')
        let NewNum = [
            ...equationNumbers,
            Number(userInput)
        ]
        setEquationNumbers([
            ...NewNum,
            Number(userInput)
        ])
        setUserInput('') 
        console.log(NewNum)
        console.log(equationNumbers)
        Calculate(operator)
        clearAllData()     
    }

    /* handle the user input inside the input field and doing operations such:+, - , /.*/
    function handleKeyDown(e){
        if(e.key === '+'){
            handleAddingOperation(e)
        }    
        else if(e.key === 'Enter'){
            handlePressingEnterKeyOrEquallButton(e)
        }       
    }
```

i tried to update the equationNumbers state using a NewNum array ' a copy of equationNumbers' then using ... method but when i console.log it. it shows only one index 'userinput' when it should has two 'the first input when user pressing + and the second userinput when pressing enter button '. so i was doing it by push method but i knew it not good because it mutates the state.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you shouldn't use `push` but create a new error with `concat` or in the way you did it.

Your error stems from something different:
`console.log(equationNumbers)` in the callback logs the `equationNumbers` value from the time the callback was created. It doesn't reflect the latest changes. `equationNumbers` was inlined, the callback contains more or less a "snapshot" from the moment the method was created.

Move the line `console.log(equationNumbers)` into the main function body and see how it changes when you enter something on every re-rendering. If this doesn't solve the issue, please reduce the example - you posts contains way too much code which is completely unrelevant for the question asked, and it's hard to see through it this way.

Comment: I want to thank you for your advice I really appreciate it. the idea about the whole code is the reader doesn't get confused about what it belongs to or I want to try this but there is something missing. but I'll try to improve it to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused with the array state update.
Do this on both your handle functions:

```
let newNum = Number(userinput);
setEquationNumbers([
   ...equationNumbers,
   newNum
]);
```

Comment: I am thankful for your supportive advice. but I've tried this before and it didn't work too.